# Insert Image on HTML button click

Tags: javascript, html

How do I insert an image into my HTML when a button is clicked?

I want to append it to the body of my HTML.

Path of image is: `/user/foo/image.png`

JavaScript

```
<script>
function addImage(){
    document.??? = "<img src='/user/foo/image.png'/>"
}
</script>
```

Comment: what does your button code look like? how do you trigger the function from the button? where should the image appear? what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) on *body* element:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img src='/user/foo/image.png'/>");
```